# compare column with text array in postgressql

Tags: database, postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL database where I have two tables with column text[] datatype. When I use an inner join to get details I do not see it is matching with any row.
for e.g.

```
create table test{
names text[],
id
}

create table test_b{
names text[],
id
}
```

now when I run below query,

```
SELECT t.* from test t inner join test_b tt
```

where t.names=tt.names;
I don't see any results. I even tried normal query with

```
SELECT * FROM test where names='{/test/test}';
```

It also did not work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide with some sample data? I assume the tables are not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want array overlap operator `&&`. Also, since you don't need to return anything from `test_b`, using `exists` with a correlated subquery is more relevant than a `join`:

```
select t.* 
from test t 
where exists (select 1 from test_b b where t.names && b.names)
```